# How to hide or show closest span with definite class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate with min value some required fields. I have several inputs. How to make validation to show or hide `.min_val` for each input - something like `closest('.min_val')`.

I tried: `$this('closest').('.min_value').css('display','none');`, but it's not working. In this case, if I've not filled all inputs, it's showing `min_val` messages. These messages should be shown for each input independent of the others. How to do that?

My code is:

```js
$(".orders-div :input").each(function () {
  var min = $(this).attr('data-min-val');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(min !== undefined && min !== null && min !== false) {
    if(value < min) {
      $(this).addClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('red');
      $('.min_value').css('display','block');
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="span2">
<label for="quantity">
    <?php echo __('Quantity'); ?>
    <span class="red">*</span>
    <span class="min_value red" style="display:none"><?php echo __('Required min value:'); ?> 1</span>
</label>

<input data-min-val='1' class="span12 required" type="text" name="quantity">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure HTML for this:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

When the form is submitted the browser will check if the input is a number and if it is between 1 and 5. If not it will throw an error.

http://jsfiddle.net/ydowpz6r/

Comment: I want to use it in this way, I'll set my message.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the HTML is set up, you need to traverse the DOM to get to the `.min_value` span that you want.

Try this:

```
$(".orders-div :input").each(function () {
  var min = $(this).attr('data-min-val');
  var value = $(this).val();

  if(min !== undefined && min !== null && min !== false) {
    if(value < min) {
      $(this).addClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('red').find('.min_value').css('display', 'block');
    }
  }
```

This will find the `.min_value` span that's contained within the closest label.

Comment: Is this code inside of some validation function you are running? when does it get called?

Comment: It is called when user press button save. I'll edit my question and I'll post my whole function.

Comment: It worked with  $(this).closest('div').addClass('red').find('.min_value').css('display', 'block');

Comment: There are no divs in the HTML you provided in the question.

Comment: I thought it's working, but now I'm testing and it's not working again.  My html looks like this for each input: <div class="span2">
                                    <label for="quantity"><?php echo __('Quantity'); ?><span class="red">*</span>
                                    <span class="min_value red" style="display:none"><?php echo __('Required min value:'); ?> 1</span></label>
                                    <input  data-min-val='1' class="span12 required" type="text" name="quantity" ">
                                </div>